# ng build --help is undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
>ng build -o dist -w
```

> The option '--o' is not registered with the build command. Run `ng
>   build --help` for a list of supported options.

```
>ng build --help
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is it not showing the help menu? If it's telling me to run `ng build --help` then that should be supported

Comment: Yes it's `undefined` but where's the question?

Comment: I was too lazy to write the question.

Comment: Did you look up the angular-cli wiki pages https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build ?

Comment: What about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the most recent version of the CLI resolved this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli